# Finding the expectation and characteristic function of a mixed distribution.

Tags: probability

I'm having difficulty with a practice exam question. Here's a modified version.

First, some notation. Let $E$ denote the exponential distribution, and $B$ the Bernoulli distribution. Also, given a random variable $X$, let us write $P_X$ for the probability distribution induced by $X$ on $\mathbb{R}$. That is

$$P_X(B) = \mathbf{P}(X \in B).$$

Then the problem is as follows.

> Let $a,b \in [0,1]$ denote real numbers such that $a+b=1$, and suppose $X$ is
>   a random variable such that $$P_X = a E(1)+b B(1/2).$$
>
> Find $\mathbf{E}(X)$ and the characteristic function $\varphi_X(t).$

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is $E$? What is $B$? Please explain your notation.

Comment: @martini, I modified the question with clarification. $E(1)$ is the exponential distribution with parameter $1$, and $B(1/2)$ the Bernoulli distribution with parameter $1/2$.

Comment: @StefanHansen, they aren't variables, they're probability distributions on the outcome space $\mathbb{R}$. You input a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and you get a real number in return, if that makes sense. We take a linear combination of these distributions to obtain a new distribution. It works because the scalars are non-negative and add to 1.

Comment: @StefanHansen, so basically $E(1)(C)$ is the probability that a random variable distributed as $E(1)$ lands in $C$. So I guess $[aE(1)+bB(1/2)](C)=a[E(1)(C)]+b[B(1/2)(C)].$

Answer (score 3):

Consider that one can *realize* $X$ as $X=UY+(1-U)Z$ where $U$ is Bernoulli independent of $(Y,Z)$ with $P(U=1)=a$ and $P(U=0)=b$, $Y$ standard exponential and $Z$ standard Bernoulli.

In particular $E(X)=aE(Y)+bE(Z)$ and $\varphi_X=a\varphi_Y+b\varphi_Z$.

Comment: Hmmm. It's not that I doubt your answer, but I don't understand how we're able to realize $X$ in this way. Can I have a bit more explanation?

Comment: Hmmm. It's not that I doubt you have spent the necessary time to analyse the gist of this construction but let us say that you try to write down what is UY+(1-U)Z when U is either 0 or 1 and that, if really some mystery remains, **then** you whistle and I add some explanations.

Comment: Sorry but I am VERY pressed for time. In particular, $2\frac{1}{2}$ hours from now I'll be in an exam. Anyway, how do we know that $\mathbf{P}(UY+(1-U)Z \in C) = aE(1)(C)+bB(1/2)(C)$?? It looks like some sort of linearity thing. Also, if $X=aY+bZ$ and $Y,Z$ independent, then $\varphi_X(t)=\varphi_Y(at)\varphi_Z(bt).$ So I don't understand how you get the formula for $\varphi_X(t).$

Comment: Anyway, probably no one will see this in time, so don't worry too much about it. I would like to understand your solution though, just out of curiosity.

Comment: If U=1 then X=Y. If U=0 then X=Z. Hence...

Comment: Oh i see Law of total probability. Anyway, thank your answer. A similar question came up in the exam and this helped tremendously.